# option select in a table is not changing

Tags: jquery, html

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" `href="file:///C:/Users/Documents/style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///C:/Users/Documents/jquery-`1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" `src="file:///C:/Users/Documents/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    $('#hpTable input').click(function() 
    {
        var $input = $(this);
        var $inputTD = $input.closest("tr");
        if( $input.prop( 'checked' ) )
        {
            var code = $inputTD.children( '#name' ).attr( "value" );
            alert( "code " + code );

            //var $numberList = $( '#popFields select:option[value=' + code + ']' ).attr( "selected", "selected" );
            //$( '#hpTable select:option[value=' + code + ']' ).attr( "selected", "selected" );
            //$numberList.val( $inputTD.children( '#numberList eq[value=' + code + ']' ).attr( "selected", "selected" ) );
            //$numberList.eq( code ).attr( 'selected', 'selected' );
            //$inputTD.find( '#numberList option' ).eq( code ).attr( 'selected', 'selected' );
            $inputTD.closet( 'select option' ).eq( '3' ).attr( 'selected', true );
         }
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="popFields">
<thead></thead>
<tbody>
    <tr><td>
        <select id="numberList">
            <option value="1" selected>one</option>
            <option value="2">two</option>
            <option value="3">three</option>
        </select>
    </td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br>
<table id="hpTable" cellpadding="5" width="100%" style="table-layout:fixed" class="tablesorter">
<thead><tr>
        <th width="9%"></th>
        <th width="9%">Date</th>
        <th width="9%">Name</th>
        <th>File</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
        <td id="date">3/3/2003</td>
        <td id="name" value="3">Bob</td>
        <td id="file">filename.doc</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Hi everyone, back again... Here I have two tables, when a user clicks on a check box, I want to display the value in the drop down list.  I seem to have tried many things, but am now getting really frustrated.  I would really appreciate any help!

By the way, can anyone recommend a good jQuery book?  Thanks!

Comment: [Learning jQuery, Third Edition](http://www.amazon.com/Learning-jQuery-Third-Jonathan-Chaffer/dp/1849516545)

Comment: Please reformat your code so that it is readable.

Comment: Your HTML is way, way, way off.  You are missing tags in your tables, `<option>` tags go nested inside a `<select>` tag.  You have text in your table that isn't inside a table cell.  There are all kinds of issues with your HTML.  You won't be able to get code to work reliably until you make the HTML correct.

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/books/jquery1/

Comment: Hey, so what is the relationship between table values and your select  box? cheers

Comment: Thanks for everyone's feedback!  alpaca lips - How do I reformat my code?  I used the ' before every line in my code?   jfriend007 - I don't see where the HTML is incorrect?  My option is nested inside a select?

Comment: @Tats_innit - there really isn't a relationship between the two. The first table is meant to display all of the second table information plus some hidden values. Hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ibuzec/2/edit#javascript,html,live)*

```
$(function() {

    $('#hpTable input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() 
    {
        var $input = $(this);
        var $inputTD = $input.closest("tr");
        if( $input.prop( 'checked' ) )
        {
            var code = $inputTD.children( '#name' ).attr( "value" );
            $('#test').html('clicked = '+ code );
            $('select#numberList option[value='+code+']').prop('selected', true);
         }
    });
});
```

Comment: it worked beautifully!  Thank you so very much!  This site is quickly becoming my favorite forum - everyone is so helpful and quick to answer questions!  :)

Comment: @sasims thanks :) And welcome to SO. but...you should really consider to visit this link. People will stop answer to your questions and help if you don't accept answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @sasim No problem! You're welcome. Just remember. vote and accept answers! And you'll be recognized among the SO community! Happy learning and happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, check your jquery. does it realy work? try to alert something when you click.

ı copied your code and tried on my own pc, its alerting "code 3".

ı recommend this books:

[http://www.amazon.com/jQuery-Pocket-Reference-David-Flanagan/dp/1449397220/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1332541159&sr=8-2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449397220)

[http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-jQuery-The-Missing-Manual/dp/1449399029/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1332541159&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449399029)

[http://www.amazon.com/jQuery-Cookbook-Solutions-Examples-Developers/dp/0596159773/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1332541159&sr=8-3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596159773)